# what's an elegant databinding design for this scenario?

Tags: angular

I have an object structure that looks like this:

```
var change = 
{
   quarters:1
   nickles:2
   dimes:3
}
```

This object should display in the html like this:

```
Change is 1 quarter, 2 nickles, 3 dimes
```

If a particular coin count is 0 then it should not be included in the message. What would be the most elegant way to implement this in ng2+?

Answer (score 1):

Call a function in your HTML File that returns the change in your wanted format:

```
 <div [innerHTML]="getChange()"></div>
```

In your ts file you write a function that return the change in your wanted format:

```
getChange(){
  return "Change is "+((change.quarters == 0) ? "" : change.quarters+" quarters, ")+((change.nickles == 0) ? "" : change.nickles+" nickles, ")+((change.dimes == 0) ? "" : change.dimes+" dimes ");
}
```

To check if one of the variables is 0 and to save yourself the hassle of writing several if statements I'd recommend using the ternary operator *(condition) ? (then) : (else)* .

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.